# Iterate through a table to display the next record with the datetime >= Today.now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to iterate through my schedules table and get one record with the 'datetime: >= Time.now' to display the current teams next game.

Here's my Team model:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :conf, :div, :full_name, :name, :short_name

  has_many :fans
  has_many :away_schedules, class_name: 'Schedule', foreign_key: :away_team_id
  has_many :home_schedules, class_name: 'Schedule', foreign_key: :home_team_id

 def schedules
  (away_schedules + home_schedules).sort_by(&:id)
  end
end
```

Here's my Schedule model:

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessible :away_team_id, :datetime, :home_team_id, :season, :week

  belongs_to :away_team, class_name: 'Team'
  belongs_to :home_team, class_name: 'Team'
end
```

I have a games_helper.rb

```
module GamesHelper
  def current_game
   @current_game = current_fan.team.schedules
  end
end
```

I have a partial _scoreboard.html.erb

```
<% current_game.each do |game| %>
  <% if game.datetime.to_s >= Time.now.to_s %>
  <% return current_game = game.datetime.to_s(:custom),
  game.away_team.short_name, " @ ", game.home_team.short_name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This seems to work but using return has the array in brackets around the results:

```
["Sun, Sep 15th, at 4:25 PM", "DEN", " @ ", "NYG"]
```

Would like it to display:

```
Sun, Sep 15th, at 4:25 PM, DEN @ NYG
```

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way.

Comment: Are you asking how to retrieve records from your database with dates greater than that value? Also, we expect to see code showing your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Hello Tin Man! I rewrote the question. I'll be more descriptive next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming an ActiveRecord model called 'Game' with a field called 'game_date':

```
Game.game_date.where('game_date > ?', Time.now).order('game_date').first
```

This will make sure your database does the sorting and searching, and only returns one record.
If you don't like the placeholder syntax, the squeel gem can make it look even more rubyish, though that's probably overkill for this example.

**UPDATE** (based on changes to the question)

I think you want to move a lot of that ruby code from the partial to your helper. In your helper, add this method:

```
def current_game_scoreboard(game)
  if game.datetime >= Time.now
    current_game = game.datetime.to_s(:custom),
      game.away_team.short_name, " @ ", game.home_team.short_name
    return current_game.join('')
  end
end
```

And in your partial just replace the body of the loop that has the above code with:

```
current_game_scoreboard(game)
```

You could improve this further by just passing a collection to the scoreboard partial and using Rails' partial magic to do the loop iteration, but this will get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in ruby :-

```
require 'date'

dtar = [ "2013-8-15 13:00:00", "2013-9-15 13:00:00","2013-12-15 13:00:00", "2013-12-5 13:00:00"]
dtar.map{|d| Date.parse d}.find{|d| d > Date.today}
# => #<Date: 2013-09-15 ((2456551j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: The OP has data in a database and is using Active Record to retrieve the data. The appropriate way to handle this is via Active Record so the logic occurs in the database manager, not in Ruby. For a tiny table the difference is negligible. For thousands or millions of rows the difference would take a Ruby-side answer to its knees and beat-up the DBM and network as rows were retrieved, sorted and thrown away, but the DBM-based logic wouldn't even slow down.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method called `next_game` to the `Team` model

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  def next_game(reload=false)
    @next_game = nil if reload
    @next_game ||= schedules.where('game_date > ?', Time.now).order('game_date').first
  end

  # change the schedules method implementation so that you can perform all the work in db
  def schedules
    Schedule.where("away_team_id = ? OR home_team_id = ?", id, id)
  end
end
```

Add a helper to display game info

```
module GamesHelper
  def game_info g
    "#{g.datetime.to_s(:custom)}, #{g.away_team.short_name} @ #{g.home_team.short_name}"
  end
end
```

Now in your view:

```
<% if (game = current_fan.team.next_game).present? %>
  <%= game_info(game)%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have simplified the implementation for `schedules` method. Try again.